# visual studio exits debugging without any exception or error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tcpclient

I have a `TCP/CLIENT` game server project in **Visual Studio 2010**. When I start the project in debug mode, some time later (sometimes 1 day, sometimes 1 week) **Visual Studio** quits debugging without any exceptions or errors. I checked the windows and application log and there is nothing unexpected there.

How can I find out what the  real problem is or what (e.g. some exceptions like stackoverflow) can cause the Visual Studio exit debugging?

Comment: Wait. You are debugging for a week? Or are you trying to debug AGAIN after a week?

Comment: you are having problem on client or server?
Put some logging

Comment: I installed a visual studio to a server and run the project there in debug mode to test. Problem occurs in server side.

Comment: But does visual studio exits? or only stops with debugging?

Comment: Only stops debugging. Such as someone connected to server and stop debugging. I have absolutely no clue why it occurs.

Comment: Have you considered memory leaks?

Comment: Running IIS? or the developmentserver cassini? or WCF http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660338/how-to-configure-your-wcf-service-to-work-as-normal-tcp-server

Comment: In server I have 12 GB memory and my project uses around 200 MB.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that your application is multithreaded. In that case uncaught exception in a background thread will crash your application. It will stop your debugger as well since it can't debug all threads at a time and should be manually swiched to a specific thread using Threads window. So the solution is to catch the exceptions in async handlers and at least log them.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (for a similar problem - not exactly this); try to reset Visual Studio environment:

```
devenv.exe /ResetSettings
```

Comment: Could you pose a theory as to how this addresses the condition?

Comment: I do not remember things from then (2010-2012) to provide a concrete answer. However I remember it was after installing some VS tools (probably ReSharper or CodeRush or something) that were meddling with debugging process itself. I think my app was ASP.NET (or MVC) and VS refused to stop at any break points. The thing is, even after uninstalling those tools; VS settings would not go back to their original form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running something as server in IIS, you can try to disable health monitoring for your server project. So open IIS and right click the application pool. Find the `Ping enabled` setting, it's under advanced settings and set it to `False`. An other option is to increase the maximum response time. This is a better solution I think. Set it to about 600 seconds.

If you are debugging for a week, use [intellitrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx).
You can use [this youtube video about intellitrace in Visual Studio 2010](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WNvUHGnVsDs) as reference.