# Visual Studio debugger stopped without any exceptions

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

I'm developing a application which has thousands of code lines. When the application is debugging it suddenly stops without giving any exceptions or error. Nothing shows in output and immediate windows.

All exceptions are checked on in Exceptions settings.

And I have read this question [visual studio exits debugging without any exception or error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790828/visual-studio-exits-debugging-without-any-exception-or-error)

I have no idea how to debug `background thread` if you can suggest me some tutorial that explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Place the widest `try/catch` you can:

```
try
{
  // your stuff
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  // place breakpoint here
  Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Place a breakpoint inside the catch and run the application in debug mode. Surely the breakpoint will be hit before application stops.

Make sure your code is well compiled, your breakpoint at runtime should not look like this:
[image]

Comment: I have tried for it but no luck. and just noted some errors on `Event Viewer` under Windows Logs> Applications. with my applications name. I still can't figure out how to fix that

Comment: Have you added a line of code in the catch? If you put the breakpoint in the curly bracket in some optimization debug scenario it could not be hit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) tool to record all method calls in your application. After your application stops execution, you will be able to see where it happened.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have breakpoints and/or try/catch in the background thread?

Comment: no breakpoints but there are few try catches in background threads.

Comment: Add some breakpoints and step through to see where it is getting an error. You can also put a try/catch around the whole thread and set a breakpoint on a string or some dummy line inside the catch, then hoover the exception ex to see the error message